# Set text in QTextBrowser with a QString that includes QProcess enums

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess, qtextbrowser

I want to write a QString that includes two QProcess enums into a QTextBrowser. Therefore I used in one of my methods:

```
QString Text = "Error! Exit-Status: " + Status + QString(" Error-Code: ") + Prozess.error() + " File not created!"

Dialog.mytextBrowser -> setText(Text);
```

This also works, but the value of the QProcess::ExitStatus "Status" and the value of Prozess.error() are missing. What do I have to change to get the values into the QTextBrowser? greetings

Comment: You can bisect the problem by writing Text to QDebug and see if the information is in the string there, if it is not than the QTextBrowser is a red herring.

Comment: I used `qDebug() << Status << Prozess.error();` and it gave me the right values.

Comment: And what if you use `qDebug() << Text;` ?

Comment: Ok, problem was solved by `QString Text = QString( "Error! Exit-Status: %1 Error-Code: %2 File not created!" ).arg( Status ).arg(Prozess.error());` . Anyway, thx for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem was solved by QString `Text = QString( "Error! Exit-Status: %1 Error-Code: %2 File not created!" ).arg( Status ).arg(Prozess.error());` . Anyway, thx for the support.